# broadcasting tensor matmul over batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, array-broadcasting

how can i find dot product of each batch response and X data.

```
y_yhat_allBatches_matmulX_allBatches = torch.matmul(yTrue_yHat_allBatches_tensorSub, interceptXY_data_allBatches[:, :, :-1])
```

expected shape of `y_yhat_allBatches_matmulX_allBatches` should be 2 by 5. where each row is for specific batch

`yTrue_yHat_allBatches_tensorSub.shape` = `[2, 15]` where rows batch (1&2) and columns = size of response (15)

`interceptXY_data_allBatches[:, :, :-1].shape = torch.Size([2, 15, 5])` for 15 observations by 5 features for 2 batches

please see full reproducible code

```
#define dataset
nFeatures_withIntercept = 5
NObservations = 15
miniBatches = 2
interceptXY_data_allBatches = torch.randn(miniBatches, NObservations, nFeatures_withIntercept+1) #+1 Y(response variable)

#random assign beta to work with
beta_holder = torch.rand(nFeatures_withIntercept)

#y_predicted for each mini-batch
y_predBatchAllBatches = torch.matmul(interceptXY_data_allBatches[:, :, :-1], beta_holder)

#y_true - y_predicted for each mini-batch
yTrue_yHat_allBatches_tensorSub = torch.sub(interceptXY_data_allBatches[..., -1], y_predBatchAllBatches)
y_yhat_allBatches_matmulX_allBatches = torch.matmul(yTrue_yHat_allBatches_tensorSub, interceptXY_data_allBatches[:, :, :-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have:

- `yTrue_yHat_allBatches_tensorSub` shaped (2, 15)
- `interceptXY_data_allBatches[:, :, :-1]` shaped (2, 15, 5)

If you want to multiply them to get a resulting shape of (2, 5), then you need to make the first one into (2, 1, 15) using `.unsqueeze(dim=1)`. Then you can use [`torch.bmm()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bmm.html) or the `@` operator to multiply (2, 1, 15) into (2, 15, 5), yielding a result shaped (2, 1, 5). Finally, `.squeeze` the result to drop the singleton dimension and get (2, 5).

```
y_yhat_allBatches_matmulX_allBatches =\
    torch.bmm(yTrue_yHat_allBatches_tensorSub.unsqueeze(dim=1),
              interceptXY_data_allBatches[:, :, :-1]
             ).squeeze()
```

More compact notation using the `@` operator:

```py
y_yhat_allBatches_matmulX_allBatches =\
    (yTrue_yHat_allBatches_tensorSub.unsqueeze(dim=1) @ interceptXY_data_allBatches[:, :, :-1]).squeeze()
```